# How do I password protect a zip file in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, node-archiver

I am creating a zip file using archiver. below is my code to do it. I need to password protect it. How can I do it?

```
var head={'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream','Content-disposition':'attachment; filename='+zipName,'Transfer-Encoding':'chunked' }

res.writeHead(200,head);

var archive = archiver('zip');

archive.pipe(res);

archive.append(result, { name: attachment.aliasFileName });

archive.finalize();

return res.send("thanks");
```

Comment: Archiver does not support passwords https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/issues/168

Comment: @prinzhorn: Can I use crypto then to password protect the zip files?

Comment: Not if you want to be zip compatible. The file could then only be read by your system and not 3rd party zip clients.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in linux you can do some thing like this

```
 //create a zip 
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    zip = spawn('zip',['-P', 'password' , 'archive.zip', 'complete path to archive file']);
    zip .on('exit', function(code) {
    ...// Do something with zipfile archive.zip
    ...// which will be in same location as file/folder given
    });
```

Refer https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html